# Converting string to datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I'm trying to enter a date in a mysql table

```
`ssdate` datetime
```

The function that produces the date can output it in 3 formats:

```
1276142400000
Thu Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT-0400 2010
Fri Jun 4 2010
```

I'm wondering which of these would be easiest to convert to this field format? 
Since I'm trying to save only the date, is there a better option than `datetime` that would work with one of these output formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the third format:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Fri Jun 4 2010'));
```

Just put the result in your datetime field. If you're going to use a date field instead you can do

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Fri Jun 4 2010'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime), but `1276142400000` does not appear to be a Unix timestamp:

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1276142400000);
+------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1276142400000) |
+------------------------------+
| NULL                         |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Perhaps it's a Unix timestamp mutiplied by 1000:

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1276142400000/1000);
+-----------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(1276142400000/1000) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 2010-06-10 06:00:00               |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

And, if unsure, you always have [STR_TO_DATE():](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Fri Jun 4 2010', '%a %b %e %Y');
+----------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Fri Jun 4 2010', '%a %b %e %Y') |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 2010-06-04                                   |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: upvote for `FROM_UNIXTIME()`, I totally agree that date conversion should be done in database if possible. However, `STR_TO_DATE()` is arguable as the whole process will then depend on locales (and maybe time-zones).

Answer (score 0):

You can set your column as a varchar(14), will work perfectly with your first format output.

Comment: ... only until 2286-11-20 17:46:39 (: Not the best way to go anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In database I would store time values in in `DATETIME` field, mainly because of built-in methods for date manipulations (`INTERVAL`, etc.). One possible alternative is to store UNIX timestamp as numeric value, but I wouldn't recommend that. If in doubt, choose standard solutions.

As for date format to convert from, I would definitely go with UNIX timestamp (#1 option in your case, multiplied by 1000 I guess) as most universal one. All other formats are locale- and timezone-dependent, which is a possible source for a lots of headaches in the future.